# Regular Expression in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am new to .NET regular expressions.

My regular expression below alerted too many `)` at run time. I don't know how to handle the `()`

```
input = "Get_MyAppList()";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"Get_([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\()$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to escape the last `)` (just before the `$`):

```
@"Get_([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\(\)$"
```

Answer (score 1):

get some regex tool that will help you create regexes that provides regex check on the fly with hints about mistakes whereabouts, generic error messages aren't good enough often.

I can recommend Expresso that I use, remember that most tricky stuff has to be preceded by

\

when you create regex (except letters & numbers basicly) 
so for `"()"` to match you need `\(\)`